# Nextjs server rendering generates much different html compared to the client rendered html

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have some react code that I am trying to move from CRA to server side rendered NextJs.

The html/css generated from the server side looks different compared to the html that is generated during the hydration phase.

There is a jarring effect due to this from the users perspective where initially the user looks at a different screen and in a few milliseconds it changes to a slightly different screen.

I am using react/typescript with redux/react query and material UI for styling.

I am prefetching the data in getServerSideProps which is all working fine.

Anyone else observed this and how to change this ?